# Polygons and actionlisteners Libgdx

Tags: libgdx, sprites

I've been browsing these forums for a while now and I nearly always am able to find an answer without having to ask my own question! Such a great community!

This is the first time I've been stumped so I hope that someone can help me, I'm just learning libgdx so any help is appreciated I know the code is rough but please be gentle as I'm learning everyday!!! :)

[image]

I'm trying to create 6 shapes with inputlisteners which eventually will return the index of the shape which will correspond to an answer, but I can only seem to get the last input listener I create to actually fire...

```
    public Panel(final int count){
    this.count = count;

    img = new Texture("badlogic.jpg");

    handlerShapeVertices = new float[]{128,30,0,256,256,256};
    handlerShape = new Polygon(handlerShapeVertices);

    triangle = new PolygonRegion(new TextureRegion(img), handlerShapeVertices,new short[]{0, 1, 2});


    triangleSprite = new PolygonSprite(triangle);

    triangleSprite.setOrigin(img.getWidth()/2,30);
    triangleSprite.setX(x);
    triangleSprite.setY(y);
    triangleSprite.setRotation(count * 60);

    handlerShape.setOrigin(triangleSprite.getOriginX(), triangleSprite.getOriginY());
    handlerShape.setPosition(x, y);
    handlerShape.rotate(count * 60);

    setBounds(x,y, 256, 256);

    addListener(new InputListener(){
        public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float xP, float yP, int pointer, int button) {
            //float [] temp = handlerShape.getTransformedVertices();

            if(resourceManager.getInstance().interSector.isPointInPolygon(handlerShape.getVertices(),0,6,xP,yP)) {
                System.out.println("CLICK INSIDE : " + count);
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

}
```

I figured the polygon.getTransformedVertices() should work and to check they were correct I drew them in as you can see by the white lines surrounding the polygonsprites however it doesn't seem to and none of the listeners are actually fired when I use that... I'm completely stumped and hope someone has some insight or can point me in the right direction? I don't want someone to write my code for me but a pointer would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I actually just figured it out, by checking all the polygons at the same time and returning the index of the polygon with the containing co-ords!

The wonders of coffee and cigarettes!!